# Supabase self-referencing many-to-many relationship failing

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I want to implement a many-to-many relationship between rows of the same table. Imagine I have a books table and I want each book to have a list of related books to be queried and displayed on my site.

I've followed the instructions from Supabase's [docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select?example=query-foreign-tables-through-a-join-table), this [post](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/joins-and-nesting) without success.

For example, imagine these two tables:

```
create table books (
  "id" serial primary key,
  "title" text
);

create table related (
  "book_id" int references books,
  "related_id" int references books,
  primary key (book_id, related_id)
);
```

If I query them as suggested in the docs I get an error.

Query:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.from('books').select(`
  id, 
  title, 
  books ( id, title )
`)
```

Error:

```
error: {
  code: 'PGRST200',
  details: "Searched for a foreign key relationship between 'books' and 'books' in the schema 'public', but no matches were found.",
  hint: null,
  message: "Could not find a relationship between 'books' and 'books' in the schema cache"
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `related (id, title)` instead of `books(…)`?

Comment: Could you follow this post to update your code? https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/4581